# Open Data for Quiz Game

Tags: data-request

I am creating a Quiz game that can contain any kind of quiz in different categories e.g. In Sports category it can be Cricket, Football etc., In Space category it can be Universe, Planets, Space Missions etc. For all that I have created the basic architecture, but I stuck on data for showing these quizzes. Where can I get this kind of data that can be used commercially?

Comment: Are you looking for quiz/trivia questions or something else?

Comment: @Skram: Yes, you are right, but I should be able to use that commercially

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067191/public-domain-trivia-database-for-game and http://ask.metafilter.com/16200/Where-to-download-Public-Domain-general-knowledge-trivia-question-bank. I dont think you're going to find a data set for you to download and import into your game. One idea would be to do some NLP on open-ish sources like Wikipedia to extract facts and turn them into questions and answers.

Comment: @skram I think that's worthy of a regular answer to this question.

Comment: @JoeGermuska okay thanks, still figuring out where the line b/w comment and answer are :)

Comment: @skram Agreed it's hard, esp. when you're not sure if you're answering the question or misinterpreting it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the following Q&As:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067191/public-domain-trivia-database-for-game
- http://ask.metafilter.com/16200/Where-to-download-Public-Domain-general-knowledge-trivia-question-bank

However, I don't think you're going to find a data set for you to download and import into your game. One idea would be to do some NLP on open-ish sources like Wikipedia to extract facts and turn them into questions and answers.

Comment: Your first link which redirects to [This link](http://www.irc-wiki.org/Category:Trivia_questions#Where_can_I_get_these_funky_new_questions.3F) is what I want, but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: Hi @RahulTaneja - what are you having trouble doing? The short answer, I think, is to go to the category pages such as http://www.irc-wiki.org/Trivia_Animals and get the numbered Q&A's. You can then seperate the question and the answer(s) using the asterisk(s)/`*`'s. You could write a scraper but considering the pages havent been updated lately, this seems like a one-time scrape and copying and pasting into Excel or something else should be fine.

Comment: Well, on the pages below you'll find all the questions, probably in categories too. For now the only way to get them is by copying & pasting them into your bot. However every 1000 questions will be put onto a paste bin, and then shared via this page. This way for those who are not contributing, you can just come and get the most recently completed files.
 
We will also put other trivia questions into pastebin pastes for you to enjoy once we find them!  

What does it mean???

Comment: Well atleast I got the data so I am marking it as answer, but I am struggling to get more questions using bot. It seems like some kind of Linux script I need to Run, however I am using Windows 8 so dont know the process.

Comment: @RahulTaneja I think the talk about the bot is only if you want to use the Q&As with the bot software this list was originally compiled for.